# Find anomaly in list of doubles

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a method that returns a list of numbers which i can not trust as sometimes i get a number that is not accurate. As an example:

```
var nums = new List<double> {675,596,125278,490,545,567,470};
```

The 125278 value clearly is an anomaly, can someone help in devising a method that will get rid of all numbers in the list that are completely out of range based on the other figures?

At the moment i am ordering the list and then getting the median however on occasion this has failed. No number should be able to exceed around 36000.

One idea would be to return the lowest value? However ideally i would like to return the last number in the list that is not an 'anomaly' e.g. from the list above 470 should be returned.

Comment: You need a precise criterion, like "an entry is anomalous iff it is more than two standard deviations away from the mean value" or something else. Deciding upon a criterion is hard to do for us (we don't know what the numbers represent). Implementing a criterion in C# code is probably a lot easier.

Comment: The only (almost) concrete thing you said was that a number should not exceed around 36,000. Other than that it's a bit unclear what the input numbers could be. This is a really vague question.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier

Comment: Why should 470 be returned? Why is that the last number that is not an anomaly?

Comment: If you're looking to exclude the extreme values, then you could use the [Interquartile range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range) and exclude values outside that. Check out [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27340/A-User-Friendly-C-Descriptive-Statistic-Class) for a C# example of how to do it.

Comment: Do you know how many values will be an anomaly (maximum)? If so, you could start peaking the maximas from the array, until the noise of your array is within a certain level.

Comment: The desired outcome it to eliminate all values that shouldn't be on the list based on the criteria that its value is an anomaly in the range.

Comment: If strange values sneak in, it is probably better to find out where they come from and close those...

Answer (score 1):

If not anomally means lower than 36000 then try this:

```
var notanomally = nums.Where(x=>x<36000); // lower than 36k
var lastnotanomally = notanomally.Last();
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This would be the first step in removing anomalies. After this i would like to go through the list again and remove all extreme values based on the majority of the other numbers...e.g. 350,1255,275,6944,300 should return 300 because the 1255 and 6944 are well over the average of the lowest three numbers

Answer (score 0):

It is not very efficient method but you can try something like this.

```
var nums = new List<double> { 675, 596, 125278, 490, 545, 567, 470 };
var removing = new List<double>();
var temp = new List<double>();
double EPSILON = 5000;

foreach (var num in nums)
{
    var average = nums.Average();
    temp = nums.Where(n => n != num).ToList();
    var average1 = temp.Average();
    if (Math.Abs(average1 - average) > EPSILON)
    {
        removing.Add(num);
    }
}

nums.RemoveAll(n=>removing.Contains(n));
```

This method temporarily removes an element and observes change in average. Significant change in average means the current value is far too large than the others.

Comment: You don't need to create a new list to evaluate the average of all but one element.

Comment: this doesnt seem to be returning a value..it returns 0

Comment: What do you mean by returns 0. Please explain

Comment: sorry my bad this seems to be working great now!

Comment: The EPSILON of 5000 means that in your method you allow values to differ by a max of 5000 correct in terms of average

Comment: EPSILON is a variable. You can adjust as per your need. May be you can apply some algorithm to adjust it dynamically based on your data set.

Comment: good idea great! Excellent reply

Comment: Hmm actually the method fails..see the following example:    var nums = new List<double> {73.0, 67, 60.58, 68.75, 176436.1, 139, 75,364178};

Comment: In this scenario your method returns an empty list as it removes all the values

Comment: I never said this is the solution. I was just trying to give you some idea to start with.

Comment: Thanks. any ideas with the revised data set?

Comment: And again adjusting the EPSILON should do the trick. For example setting it to 15000 should solve this thing.